# Generating Report on Contacts without Activities

Tags: reporting

How can I generate a report on `Contacts` Without Activities?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess my answer wasnt good enough.Oh well. Lesson learned:dont spend more than 15 seconds replying to guys with 1 reputation =)

Answer (score 0):

Use cross filter on a suitable report type[image]